# RStudio crashes *after* calling an Rcpp function multiple times

Tags: rstudio, rcpp

I've written some Rcpp code to find intersections in two piecewise linear curves. I approached the problems in the naive way requiring nested loops (checking all pairs of segments), so went to Rcpp for speed. (The problem is pictorially described in "Example 1" here: https://prezi.com/rwkji_leuwdr/r-and-c-integration/ )

The code compiles fine with sourceCpp, and even runs fine and gives expected results.  BUT, the strange issue is that it consistently crashes RStudio either after running it multiple times (say, 5 or 6), or a little while after running it.  I haven't seen anyone else document this sort of problem in a google/stack overflow search.  I'm new to C++ and don't have any kind of intuition as to where the problem is coming from; seems like pretty weird behavior to me given that the functions run as desired at first.

Code and data are here: https://github.com/suztolwinskiward/ReproducepRoblem

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps!

Comment: Experience with compiled code, and hours spent debugging, teaches us that this is rather unlikely to have anything to do with RStudio with merely happens to your shell.  You have a bug, and you need to find it.  Sorry for being bearer of bad news here but there is strictly no sugar-coating.

Comment: Ugh, found it. Embarrassing, but thanks for solidifying my trust in RStudio.

Comment: Nice work!  Debuggers can sometimes help, but they too have a learning curve.

Comment: @SuzTolwinski-Ward I'm having a similar issue, care to share what the bug was?

Comment: @SuzTolwinski-Ward It was due to memory. Calling the garbage collector after calls resolved the problem.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde. Thought I had resolved this issue way back when, but recently was calling a version of the code many times in a row- and found it still crashed at random after 100s/1000s of calls. Smelled like a memory leak,so I changed the functions to return void & passed everything I needed in by reference, so that the Rcpp part of my solution just modified the input variables defined in R in place.  Eliminating memory allocation within the C++ code eliminated the crashes. So still not sure Rcpp does all the memory deallocation completely automagically, or if I'[m misusing it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the same problem and the bug seemed to be that I was trying to allocate too much data to a vector. It might be helpful to use the `()` operator rather than the `[]` operator in Rcpp. With `[]` my code would compile and crash after I ran it a few times; with `()` the code will compile but it'll throw an error at runtime.