# R crashes/aborts using Rcpp with NA input

Tags: c++, r, rstudio, rcpp, na

I want to process two raster images (Ra and Rb), with Ra is the pixel value itself and Rb the values of its neighbors. taking sum as an example, assuming an 3*3 neighbors, for each pixel in Ra I will add its value to values of the neighbor pixels in Rb, an finally i will get another image.

The R raster package provides a focal function, which works only on one image input, i tried to modify the C++ code ([enter link description here](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/src/focal_fun.c)) to accept two image input using Rcpp. The modified code works well if there is no missing values in the input image of Rb. However, R always aborts if there is NA in Rb. Specifically, abort at the second or third test. it may be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768796/rstudio-crashes-after-calling-an-rcpp-function-multiple-times). however, it did not crash if no NA in the input Rb. It seems i did not handle NA correctly. I do not have deep knowledge on C++, Can somebody help me check this?

here is my cpp file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include "Rdefines.h"
#include "R_ext/Rdynload.h"

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector focal_quantile(NumericVector xd, int ngbb, NumericVector sf) {
  //the imges are transfered to vector, ngbb is the size of the window  
  R_len_t i, j, k, q;
  int wrows = ngbb;
  int wcols = ngbb;
  int wn = wrows * wcols;

  int nrow = 6;//the input raste has 6 rows
  int ncol = 7;//the input raste has 7 cols

  int n = nrow * ncol;
  NumericVector xans(n);
  NumericVector xx(wn);

  int wr = floor(wrows / 2);
  int wc = floor(wcols / 2);

  int nwc = ncol - wc - 1;
  int col = 0;

  // first rows
  for (i = 0; i < ncol*wr; i++) {// the first row, the resutl is set as NA as the neighbor does not have nine values   
    xans[i] = R_NaReal; 
  }

  for (i = ncol*wr; i < (ncol * (nrow-wr)); i++) {//start from the second row
    col = i % ncol;
    if ((col < wc) | (col > nwc)) {//the first pixel of the second is also set as NA
      xans[i] = R_NaReal;
    } else {// to get the nine values in the 3*3 windows
      q = 0;
      for (j = -wr; j <= wr; j++) {
        for (k = -wc; k <= wc; k++) {
          xx[q] = xd[j * ncol + k + i]; 
          q++;
        }
      }
      xx = na_omit(xx);
      int n_qt = xx.size();
      if (n_qt > 0){//
        xans[i]=sum(xx)+100*sf[i];// here is the calculation, my goal is more complicated than this example
      } else {
        xans[i] = R_NaReal;//R_NaReal
      }

    }
  }
  // last rows
  for (i = ncol * (nrow-wr); i < n; i++) {  
    xans[i] = R_NaReal;
  }
  return(xans);
}
```

Then compile it using sourceCpp

generate example data to test it

```
  rr=raster(nrow=6,ncol=7)## example for Ra
  projection(rr)="+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"
  rr[]=(2:43)*10
  rrqt=rr/43 ## example for Rb
  ##it works fine, if there is no NA in Ra
  #rr[1:10]=NA #window of global enviornment is refleshing and then aborts with such NAs 
  focal_quantile(rr[],3,rrqt[])
```

Example results

```
 [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA 118918.6 130810.5 142702.3 154594.2 166486.0       NA       NA
[16] 202161.6 214053.5 225945.3 237837.2 249729.1       NA       NA 285404.7 297296.5 309188.4 321080.2 332972.1       NA       NA 368647.7
[31] 380539.5 392431.4 404323.3 416215.1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

resulted NA is acceptable as there are not nine values in the windows.
For such example, i change the values of raster rr (with no NA). it works smoothly. when I introduce NA in rr, for example the sixth row of the codes above. the Global environment window is refreshing and Rstudio aborts.

the session information is

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.12.11 raster_2.5-8 sp_1.2-3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rgdal_1.2-5     tools_3.3.0     grid_3.3.0      lattice_0.20-35
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should only be using the `#include <Rcpp.h>` statement. The other headers you are adding are *not* needed or already included within `Rcpp.h`.

---

Secondly, the correct way to reference the `NA` value for `NumericVector`s within Rcpp is to use the `NA_REAL` **not** R's `R_NaReal`.

---

Thirdly, you have an out of bounds error. If you switch the parentheses from `[]` to `()` you have bounds detection. The error on Rcpp 0.12.11 is:

> "Index out of bounds: [index=3; extent=3]."

As a result, this is creating an ["Undefined Behavior" (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) that triggers the crash of RStudio.

The problematic line is:

```
xx(q) = xd(j * ncol + k + i); 
^^^^^
```

Now, you might say this doesn't make sense as the length of `xx` should never be 3. However, the reason this line is problematic is because you are changing the values that are found in `xx` when you drop the `NA` values with:

```
xx = na_omit(xx);
```

You should really declare a new `xy` vector if this is the aim or update the constants to ensure the out of bounds error is avoided.

---

#### Implementation

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector focal_quantile(Rcpp::NumericVector xd,
                                   int ngbb,
                                   Rcpp::NumericVector sf) {
  //the imges are transfered to vector, ngbb is the size of the window  
  R_len_t i, j, k, q;
  int wrows = ngbb;
  int wcols = ngbb;
  int wn = wrows * wcols;

  int nrow = 6;//the input raste has 6 rows
  int ncol = 7;//the input raste has 7 cols

  int n = nrow * ncol;
  Rcpp::NumericVector xans(n);
  Rcpp::NumericVector xx(wn);

  int wr = floor(wrows / 2);
  int wc = floor(wcols / 2);

  int nwc = ncol - wc - 1;
  int col = 0;

  // first rows
  for (i = 0; i < ncol*wr; i++) {// the first row, the resutl is set as NA as the neighbor does not have nine values   
    xans[i] = NA_REAL; 
  }

  for (i = ncol*wr; i < (ncol * (nrow-wr)); i++) {//start from the second row
    col = i % ncol;
    if ((col < wc) | (col > nwc)) {//the first pixel of the second is also set as NA
      xans[i] = NA_REAL;
    } else {// to get the nine values in the 3*3 windows
      q = 0;
      for (j = -wr; j <= wr; j++) {
        for (k = -wc; k <= wc; k++) {
          xx[q] = xd[j * ncol + k + i]; 
          q++;
        }
      }
      Rcpp::NumericVector xx_subset = na_omit(xx);
      int n_qt = xx_subset.size();
      if (n_qt > 0){//
        xans[i]=sum(xx_subset)+100*sf[i];// here is the calculation, my goal is more complicated than this example
      } else {
        xans[i] = NA_REAL;//NA_REAL
      }

    }
  }

  // last rows
  for (i = ncol * (nrow-wr); i < n; i++) {  
    xans[i] = NA_REAL;
  }
  return(xans);
}
```

Test case:

```
library("raster")
rr = raster(nrow=6,ncol=7)## example for Ra
projection(rr) = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"
rr[] = (2:43)*10
rrqt = rr/43 ## example for Rb
rr[1:10] = NA 
focal_quantile(rr[],3,rrqt[])
```

Output:

```
 [1]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA  742.5581  915.8140 1099.0698 1292.3256
[13] 1375.5814        NA        NA 1625.3488 1828.6047 2041.8605 2265.1163 2378.3721        NA        NA 2718.1395 2831.3953
[25] 2944.6512 3057.9070 3171.1628        NA        NA 3510.9302 3624.1860 3737.4419 3850.6977 3963.9535        NA        NA
[37]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

---

**Side note**

If you look at the code you are trying to translate, note that there is an [`naonly`](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/56aeee1b079142c36372cde85d1c9907fe96bff1/src/focal_fun.c#L53-L119) part followed by na components. So, the translation is not necessarily 1-1.

Comment: Coatless, Thank you very much for your valuable help. What a simple mistake i made. I will be double careful in future. in my side, i process all data, not naonly. Thank you again.